# Passing JSON Values to an API call in Python for GCP

Tags: python, json, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

This is my first post here, so I appreciate you bearing with me on this. let me try and step you through what I am trying to do:

I have a json file (compute.json) that has the values for creating a compute instance in the google cloud.

I am trying to write a python API call to GCP that:
- Loads the compute.json file
- decodes the json file
- serialized the data to be passed to the GCP API

I'm currently getting a " is not JSON serializable"
- I am having trouble serializing the data for the API call.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
from pprint import pprint
import json
import requests

auth = json.load(open('auth.json'))

key = auth["private_key"]

compute_json = json.load(open('Compute.json'))
contents = json.dumps(compute_json)

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECTID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances'

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
params = {'key': key}

requests.port(url, params=params, data=contents, headers=headers)
response = request.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

So my questions are:

A) How do I 're-serialize' the data to send to the API

B) is their an easy way to pass a Formatted JSON file to an API without decoding, recoding, and serializing the data?

Thanks everyone!